# CSS animated header with screen sliding (no JS)

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create simple auto-hide menu/header with css. I use transition but I think this is not a point here.
When I hover header is should slide down and show whole content, when I move mouse away it should slideup. It works for me. I want also screen content to expand when header is slidedup. This is mayor problem. The only way I know to have div expanded on whole page (screen) is to fix its top, bottom, left & right. It does not work when top value is changing.

Please look at my code example:
http://jsbin.com/ahamid/2/edit

The green part is problematic. I tried to fix it with changing top value on hover - but it does not work when mouse is outside of content & outside of header too.

Below is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="head">
      <span> header </span>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <span>
        test content
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and css:

```
    body { 
  position: relative;
}
#main { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}
#head { 
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  top: -44px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #fcc;
  margin: 0px 3px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
}
#head:hover { 
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  top:0px;
  transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
}
#content { 
  background-color: cfc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 3px;
  transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
}
#head span { 
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 transition: 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
 -o-transition: 0.5s;
}
#head:hover span { 
  color: yellow;
  transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
}
#content:hover { 
  top: 6px;
 transition: 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
 -o-transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you set the #content as you want it to be on hover.

What you really want is that it is always that way, and only change it (downwards; increasing top) in the hover of the #head

Change the #content to:

```
#content { 
    background-color: cfc;
    .....
    top: 6px;
    .....
}
```

and modify the top in the hover of the head:

```
#head:hover ~ #content { 
   top: 50px;
   transition: 0.5s;
   -moz-transition: 0.5s;
   -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
   -o-transition: 0.5s;
}
```

You can do that because head and content are siblings, so you can use the sibling selector.

This way it behaves correctly, the only strange thing comes from the transitions timing being different, but you can manage this :-)

Comment: Thanks! That works perfect!
Here is working result: http://jsbin.com/ahamid/7 
I compressed css little bit & tried it with "adjacent sibling selector" and also works good.